# MAX Function not finding MAX value

Tags: mysql

I have this `SELECT` statement that I have been working on for a week. I have figured everything out the way we need it. However we needed all the agents to be `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` the `MAX` number in for that agent. This works some times but not all the time.

For example with the below query if you look at the `agentID` deramsey it is only finding the highest value of 8.5, but it's suppose to be 11.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02e2e/2

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? And where's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry the main query is suppose to run some calculations, whichI have working. This one is suppose to `GROUP` those by the `agentID` and find the `MAX` number for each agent.

Comment: So, for simplicity, can you construct a VIEW showing the intermediate result? I.e. Just the calculated results without the MAX bit

Comment: @Strawberry Yes http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02e2e/7 this is the result.

Comment: I can't really be bothered to wade through all that but basically your calculation is casting an integer to a string. Just cast it back again, and it should work - so SELECT agentid,MAX(total+0) FROM(my query) x GROUP BY agentid;

Comment: Thank you, that definitely did the trick.